# Product image not displaying in product page(view.phtml)

Tags: image, magento, product

Product image not displaying in product page of magento. Where as its showing in list and grid. It is due to an extension which i installed and uninstalled, since that the product image is not showing up, Even the view.phtml is not calling the media.phtml. Please any suggestions ...

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could replace view.phtml with your original file, which could could copy from the base template into your custom template

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/[yournamespace]/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

You may also need to delete any layout xml files installed by the module, incase it has made changes to the layout of the view page

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/[moduleslayout].xml
```